# find duplicate rows containing various types of lists (of lists) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, duplicates

**Background**

I have the following `df` that contains a mix of list types

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Size' : [[[['small', 'small', 'big', 'big']]], [['big', 'small','small']], ['big'], ['big']], 
                  'ID': [1,2,3,3], 
                  'Animal' : [['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat'], ['dog', 'pig','dog'], ['pig'], ['pig']]

                 })
```

Which looks like this

```
    Animal                ID    Size
0   [cat, dog, dog, cat]    1   [[[small, small, big, big]]]
1   [dog, pig, dog]         2   [[big, small, small]]
2   [pig]                   3   [big]
3   [pig]                   3   [big]
```

**Problem**

I use the following

```
df.duplicated()
```

I get the following error since my dataframe contains list (at least I think this is why)

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

**Question**

How do I check for duplicate rows in a dataframe that contains multiple types of lists?

Comment: Hot take: Maintaining columns of lists are a bad idea for precisely this reason: Any solution for this problem now requires deceptive hacks and trickery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas drop\_duplicates method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855462/pandas-drop-duplicates-method-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.astype(str).drop_duplicates().index]
```